# Reading a JPEG in Char

Tags: c, jpeg

So I want to read a JPEG to send it via a socket to a browser. 
But I keep having problems with reading in the JPEG. 
My Code:

```
FILE* fp = fopen(filename, "rb"); 
if( fp == NULL)
    { 
        fp = fopen(FILE_404, "r");
    } else
    {

        struct stat fst;
        stat(filename, &fst);
        unsigned char *blob;


        blob = (unsigned char *)malloc(fst.st_size);

        fread(blob, 1, fst.st_size, fp);

        header->content = (unsigned char*)malloc(fst.st_size);

        strcat(header->content, blob);
        header->content[fst.st_size+1] = "\0";
        header->content_len = fst.st_size;

    }
```

But all get when printing out blob is:`\377\330\377\340` although the file is : 67165 byte big. 
What can I do?

Comment: Neither `header->content` nor `blob` are strings so how can you  use `strcat` function?

Comment: You're completely right (Sorry I'm developing this thing for hours now, I'm getting tired). I fixed that, but the problems occurs earlier. It seems like the fread is not reading in everything.

Comment: For one, you're not checking the return value of fread(), which will tell you how much got read. Also, it's raw binary, so how exactly are you "printing" it?  You can't use string functions like printf().

Comment: 1) the contents of header->content has not been set to '\0' so strcat would not work, even if they were strings.  2) this line: 'header->content[fst.st_size+1] = "\0";' is setting a byte beyond the end of the header->content buffer, leading to undefined behaviour and possibly a seg fault event.  3) the returned value from a call to malloc, stat, fread all need to be checked to assure successful operation (2 places). 4) jpeg images can have 0x00 bytes, so use memcpy not strcat.

Answer (score 1):

1. `strcat(header->content, blob);` does not make sense for binary data.  `strcat()` works with strings.  @ouah
2. The following is undefined behavior as `content[fst.st_size+1]` is out of bounds.

   ```
   reader->content = (unsigned char*)malloc(fst.st_size);
   ...
   header->content[fst.st_size+1] = ...
   ```
3. Code appears to want to append a null character `'\0'` to the array.  Appending a pointer to string `"0"` is not the same.  IAC, appending a null character is not the solution.

   ```
   header->content = (unsigned char*)malloc(fst.st_size);
   .... 
   // bad code
   header->content[fst.st_size+1] = "\0";
   ```
4. Check return value of `fread(blob, 1, fst.st_size, fp);` before using the data in `blob`. @Lee Daniel Crocker   Also should check return value of `stat()`.
5. Minor:  No need to cast `malloc()` return.

   ```
   // blob = (unsigned char *)malloc(fst.st_size);
   blob = malloc(fst.st_size);
   ```
6. To print the contents of `blob`, after successful reading into it via `fread()`

   ```
   size_t i;
   for (i = 0; i<fst.st_size; i++) {
     printf(" %02X",  blob(i));
   }
   ```